# Remove characters from string when passing as parameter

Tags: bash, parameters

I've tried Googling this and tested every permutation I could come up with, but I'm just not getting it. :(

I have a function which accepts an identified input string:

```
[user@Dreadnaught /]$ myfunction -w InputString
```

The function has several input options, so I need to identify that I'm passing my string to the -w option. The string I'm getting from another program has dashes in it:

```
In-put-St-ring
```

I can remove those dashes when testing an echo:

```
[user@Dreadnaught /]$ echo "In-put-St-ring" |tr -d -
InputString
```

But I can't figure out how to strip the dashes when passing to the function. I've tried (unsuccessfully):

```
[user@Dreadnaught /]$ OldString="In-put-St-ring"
[user@Dreadnaught /]$ echo $OldString
In-put-St-ring
[user@Dreadnaught /]$ NewString=$OldString|tr -d -
[user@Dreadnaught /]$ echo $NewString

[user@Dreadnaught /]$ NewString=$($OldString|tr -d -)
-ash: In-put-St-ring: not found
[user@Dreadnaught /]$ NewString=$("$OldString"|tr -d -)
-ash: In-put-St-ring: not found
[user@Dreadnaught /]$ NewString=$(""$OldString"|tr -d -")
-ash: In-put-St-ring|tr -d -: not found
```

and...

```
[user@Dreadnaught /]$ myfunction -w $("In-put-St-ring" |tr -d -)
-ash: In-put-St-ring: not found
myfunction: option requires an argument -- 'w'
```

and... a few more.

I'm sure it's simple for someone with more bash experience than me, but I'm stumped. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does your function honor the `--` option, to "Delimit the option list"?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to use `echo`.

A pipe doesn't send *variables* to a command – a pipe connects one command's *output* to the other command's input. That is, the whole `echo "In-put-St-ring"` is first processed and only then its output is sent to `tr`; not the other way around.

In other words, every time a pipe is used, you can interpret it like this:

```
(echo "$OldString") | (tr -d -)
```

Because the syntax used inside `$( ... )` substitution is exactly the same as in the "main" command line, you also need to use `echo` to actually *produce* the variable's contents as output before they can be piped:

```
NewString=$(echo "$OldString" | tr -d -)

myfunction -w "$(echo "$OldString" | tr -d -)"
```

That said, there is actually an alternative bash-specific method to pipe just some text without a whole command (although it's not necessarily better; in some cases perhaps even worse):

```
NewString=$(tr -d - <<< "$OldString")

myfunction -w "$(tr -d - <<< "$OldString")"
```

But instead of either, you should just use [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
NewString=${OldString//-}

myfunction -w "${OldString//-}"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Specifically, the parameter expansion method should be used.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @grawity. The first version works, but unfortunately the second two aren't working for me when I try to use them directly. So
'NewString="In-put-St-ring"
myfunction -w ${NewString//-}'
works, but
'myfunction -w ${"In-put-St-ring"//-}'
doesn't work.

Comment: It only applies to variables, not string literals. But as you've said in the question, you're getting the string from another program, so it'll be a variable anyway...